# Giving object in dll a click method from another project

Tags: c#

is it possible to adding a click method to a class in dll from another project?
I want to create a class (Class1) in a class library and build a dll from it.
I will use that class in a project with references the dll.
This is my class (Class1)

```
public class Class1
{
    public ImageMap map = null;
    public Class1(Form f)
    {
        map = new ImageMap();

        map.RegionClick += f.RegionMap_Clicked;
    }
}
```

and this is my form (Form1) in another project.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Class1 c = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        c = new Class1(this);
    }

    void RegionMap_Clicked(int index, string key)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(key);
    }
}
```

This is my first time asking here. So, sorry if my english is bad.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Being in a DLL doesn't change anything. What's the question? Have you *tried* it?

Comment: Yes, i already try this. but its not working. the DLL can't be build. It doesn't recognize Form1 because it is build in another solution.

Comment: Are you trying to add the event handler from inside the DLL or from the project containing Form1?

Comment: The problem is that what you're trying to do requires a [circular reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719730/how-to-deal-with-circular-references) between your application and your DLL.

Comment: i want to add the event which is declared in Form1 to an object in Class1 in DLL.

Comment: Oh yes, i think i need that circular reference stuff. So, basically i have to create another project connecting this 2 project? or is there a way to create a pointer to the event handler and passing the pointer to the class?

Comment: Have you considered using delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class1 can be made independent from Form1:

```
public class Class1
{
    public ImageMap Map = null;

    public Class1()
    {
        this.Map = new ImageMap();
    }
}
```

And Form1 uses Class1 however it likes:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Class1 c = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.c = new Class1();
        this.c.Map.RegionClick += this.RegionMap_Clicked;
    }

    private void RegionMap_Clicked(int index, string key)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(key);
    }
}
```

Thus only the Form1 project needs a reference to the Class1 project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, don't forget to make your handler public:

```
public void RegionMap_Clicked(int index, string key)
{
    MessageBox.Show(key);
}
```

Comment: i can't passing Form1 to Class1 constructor parameter because it is create in another project.

Comment: It's not a problem, have you added a reference to assambly with Form1? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
public class Class1
{
    public ImageMap map = null;
    public Class1(Form1 f)
    {
        map = new ImageMap();

        map.RegionClick += f.RegionMap_Clicked;
    }
}
```

then

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Class1 c = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        c = new Class1(this);
    }

    public void RegionMap_Clicked(int index, string key)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(key);
    }
}
```

and of couse you shold add using for this assembly.

I think now it will be working well

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this can't be used because the Class1 and the Form1 is in the different solution. So, the Form1 can use the Class by "using the.dll" but the class can't use Form1 as a parameter.

Comment: Do you mean the different solution is app and Form1 in the exe file? Right? So you can move Form1 code into a new solution as dll and used in app and with Class as dll.